# Wpf Grid, how to set Row , Column programarically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid with 5 rows, 5 columns, an need to add some paths programmatically, and need to set row an column to,each new path,

how can I do to set both , if SetRow, an SetColumn doesn't appear to be valid methods at my code behind?

My real,problem,is that those properties doesn't appear at my class.

the class is:
system.Windows.Controls.Grid

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Grid` class has two **static** methods for that purpose [`Grid.SetRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Grid.SetColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Grid.SetRow(myControl, 1)
Grid.SetColumn(myControl, 1)
```

This will set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties for `myControl`

Comment: It works whit system.Windows.Controls.Grid ? Somethig assembly missed?

Comment: What do you mean? These are static methods so you cannot call them from instance of Grid. You need to call them through Grid class type

Comment: Tks, sorry for my Ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

They are attached properties, meaning you should call them view Grid.SetRow...